# Symfony 2 Error in Configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed symfony from the tutorial [Tutorial](http://symfonytuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/starting-up-the-project.html).The installation is ok and it shows me the Welcome page but when i click on `configure your symfony app` it gives the following error
`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig.php on line 48`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are differences between zip and tar.gz archives. If you are working on windows, I recommend download and use zip archive of Symfony standard edition.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote a post about this on my blog in polish [link points to the page translated to english]:

http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.kowalczyk.cc%2F2011%2F04%2F01%2Fsymfony2-fatal-error-class-resolvedefinitiontemplatespass-not-found-in-pathpassconfig-php-on-line-line%2F

In general, the conclusion is that .tgz archives have some parts missing, and you must use .zip in order to get the full package.